# Batch script not running completely

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation

This is first time I am dealing with batch files.
I have a java project with ant. I have divided the project into two sub projects. I tried building the projects using a batch file in sequential manner.
Here is the content of my .bat file.:

```
start cmd
cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java2
ant run

cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java3
ant run
```

The first three lines run properly, but after that nothing happens. The last two lines are not working. Am I missing something, or is there any alternate way to run these subprojects sequentially?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

is `ant` a batch file?

If so, try (or try anyway)

```
CALL ant run
```

OR

```
START "windowname" ant run
```

where you can add `/wait` to the `START` command to have the batch wait for the first `ant` to finish before proceeding.

see

```
`start /?`
```

from the prompt for docco.

---

(following comment)

Here is your original code:

```
start cmd
cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java2
ant run

cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java3
ant run
```

What this should have done is:

1. Start a brand-new CMD window
2. change to the specified sirectory
3. Start the executable `ant` with the parameter `run`

Now - I've just downloaded `ANT` and I find that it includes `ANT.BAT` and `ANT.CMD` but NOT `ANT.EXE`.

In your environment, you would have a variable called `PATHEXT` whis is a semicolon-separated list of the valid executable extensions, in order of selection. In all probability, unless you've taken specific action to change it, this will be `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

What this means is that the ANT that will be executed is `ANT.BAT` if you've added its directory to your path (which, I believe, is in the instructions)

So executing the `ANT.BAT` will TRANSFER execution to `ANT.BAT`.

SO:

I see no reason why you are producing a new `CMD` window.

```
cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java2
CALL ant run

cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java3
CALL ant run
```

should work.

```
cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java2
START /wait "First ANT" ant run

cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java3
START /wait "Second ANT" ant run
```

should also work.

Note the position of the `/wait` If it follows the `start` then cmd knows it's a `start` parameter. If it follows `ant` then cmd will assume it's an `ant` parameter.

The /wait simply tells CMD to WAIT until the executable is finished before continuing.

This:

```
cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java2
START "First ANT" ant run

cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java3
START "Second ANT" ant run
```

should also work, but this time the second ANT instance will be started in parallel with the first (well, milliseconds later)

Note also the `"quoted string"` before the `ant`. The syntax of the START statement is to allow a `"quoted string"` as a window title. The quoted string may be empty `""` if you wish. You can even omit the quoted string altogether EXCEPT if the executable is quoted, in which case the window title is `required`.

Comment: ant is not a batch file. Its the apache ant command to build a project.

Comment: Here is what I tried:
start cmd
cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java2
/wait ant run
cd /d C:\Users\MeUser\Downloads\selenium-grid-1.0.8\examples\java3
/wait ant run

But its not even running the first three lines also.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav: As far as Windows is concerned, the `ant` that you are calling *is* a batch file. Just use `CALL ant run` instead of `ant run` and you should be fine. Also, the `start cmd` is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: @PeterWright: The above solution works, but there is a problem. The 'call ant run' is not working for the directory to which I changed for using 'cd' command. ant run is working for the directory where the batch file is present. Looks like the change of directory does not have any effect.